# Attaching files using sendgrid web api v3 - Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm trying to send some attachments (images) using Sendgrid web api v3, since the official Android library doesn't work for the moment.

The problem that I'm having is related to encoding the Bitmap file into base64 string. 
This is my encoding function:

```
fun BitMapToString(bitmap: Bitmap?): String {
    val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bitmap!!.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, baos)
    val b = baos.toByteArray()
    return Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT)
}
```

This is how I attach the images in the JSON (where imageAttachment is the result of calling BitMapToString(bitmapImage)):

```
...
"attachments": [
                    {
                        "content": "$imageAttachment",
                        "filename": "Test.jpg"
                    }
                ],
...
```

I'm using OkHTTP for creating the request. 
Every time I'm trying to send the email I get:

Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=Bad Request, url=https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send }

I think that I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what. Can anyone help with this?